# SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, npm, https

jenkins build failing with the below error when its trying to clone a git repository during build

> Error:- npm ERR! fatal: unable to access
> 'https://organization.host.com/example-repo.git/': SSL peer handshake
> failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to
> connect.

in the package.json, this was mentioned with
"git+https://organization.host.com/example-repo.git#tab

Please help

I tried setting,

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

[http "https://code.example.com/"]
sslCAinfo = /path/to/<downloaded certificate>

and no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: If the server requires the client to authenticate itself with a certificate you must actually provide this certificate and this certificate need to be trusted by the server. This means that you need to have both the certificate itself and the matching key and configure it with sslCert and sslKey. Ask whoever maintains the git server for their requirements regarding the client certificates and how to get these. sslverify and sslCAinfo are irrelevant for this, since they are about validating the client validating the server certificate, not the server validating the client certificate.

Comment: sure, I am going to send an email. But one note, this was working fine and suddenly started failing in Mac alone (working in Linux and windows setup).

Comment: There can also be other reasons why the handshake fails, like changed requirements on the server regarding TLS protocol or ciphers or some middlebox or local antivirus fiddling with the connections. In none of these cases disabling certificate validation helps though